# Get one image from google image search for a word in android

Tags: android

There is an activity with `ImageView` inside.
I want to get the first image of google image search and place it as image source.
i think it is possible, i found something similar on a translation application.

Is there any api available for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check Google Custom Search API, that alows filter by type

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

The request will be something like

> https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?googlehost=google.co.uk&safe=medium&searchType=image&key={apikey}&cx={cseId}&q={search}

See more here
https://lornajane.net/posts/2013/doing-google-custom-search-via-api

To use the images as a source, you can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) Lib

Comment: your answer woks for me. only remember there is an option for image search in CSE and that option must be on yes (default is no unfortunately).